unity wheel collider moving slow after adding large amout of value
I have tried a simple car movement in Unity. I add large amount of values but vehicle moving too slow. I tried with static values but still moving very slow.
I didn't made any canges in wheel collider using it's default values, just its radius to setup. Mass of rigidbody is 1500
[SerializeField] private WheelCollider frontLeftWheelCollider, frontRightWheelCollider;
[SerializeField] private WheelCollider rearLeftWheelCollider, rearRightWheelCollider;

private void FixedUpdate(){

    frontLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = 100000 * 10;
    frontRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = 100000 * 10;

    rearLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = 100000 * 10;
    rearRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = 100000 * 10;
}





spring and damper sounds quite huge as well

@derHugo these are default values. I didn't made any changes
